# Printer Enclosure Material Selection

Tags: enclosure

Im planning on building an enclosure for my CR-10S and am debating whether to use MDF walls lined with an insulation foam that reduces noise and keeps the heat in or going with double pane glass walls.

My main concern is not necessarily keeping the enclosure hot as it is for noise reduction. Obviously the wood with insulation will give better sounds dampening, but I am wondering if anyone has tried both or at least heard a printer before and after with both and if the glass alone had a significant effect on the sounds reduction.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the noise, you could replace the metal linear bearings for plastic ones. This reduces the produced noise considerably from experience. Also, put the printer on damping rubber feet.

Enclosing the printer should be done with care, completely boxing the printer up could lead to increased temperatures of your board electronics, steppers and cold end cooling. Make sure to vent some air. How you box up does not matter, although double glass window panes does seem a bit of an expensive solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a type of 1/2" insulation foam available in the US that my shop uses. Here's [a link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GAF-0-5-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-EnergyGuard-PolyIsocyanurate-Insulation-Sheathing-1S01/204322721) to it at Home Depot. It's pretty tough so long as you aren't hanging things off it, and you could build a frame out of 2"x4" beams to pressure fit squares in there. It's also massively sound dampening.